# Show that every measurable set $A$ can be written $A=B \cup C$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Show that every measurable set $A$ can be written $A=B \cup C$ where $B=\cap_{i=1}^\infty O_i$ ($O_i$ are open) and $C$ is measure $0$.

How should one approach this and can someone refer me to a good text that addresses expressing a measurable set in terms of a $C$ with measure $0$?

Comment: What is a open set for you? Is the measure complete?

Comment: There's a difference between a set with measure 0 and a null set.

Comment: Thanks, corrected. I'm interpreting the measure as the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: The only proof that comes to mind is by transfinite induction on the Borel hierarchy, and using the fact that every Lebesgue measurable set is a Borel set with an additional null set. But it's 3am, and I'm very tired. So maybe there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't read your problem carefully the first time. This is false: Take for example a meager set A of reals whose complement is null set.

It seems to me that you wanted to get a $G_{\delta}$ set containing $X$ such that the residual is null. This is a consequence of regularity of Lebesgue measure. A proof will depend of what a measurable set of reals is to you. One standard definition is (see Oxtoby for example): X is measurable if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist closed and open sets $F_{\epsilon}, U_{\epsilon}$ resp. such that $F_{\epsilon} \subseteq X \subseteq U_{\epsilon}$ and $\mu(U_{\epsilon} \backslash F_{\epsilon}) < \epsilon$. In this case the proof is trivial, by taking the intersection of $U_{\epsilon}$ as $\epsilon$ runs over all positive rationals gives you the desired $G_{\delta}$ cover. If this isn't your definition then you should state your definition (maybe it is Caratheodory outer measurable) and I will supply the necessary argument.

Comment: The definition of measurability I've been given is $A$ is measurable if there is an open set $O \supset E$ such that $O \backslash E = O \cap E^c$ and $m_*(O\backslash E) \leq \epsilon$ where $m_*$ is the outer measure.

Comment: I do think I mean outer measure. In Royden (the text which I've been following), the measure is derived after a long discussion on outer measure. Does this change what you've said?

Comment: Okay. This is exactly regularity. For each rational $\epsilon > 0 $ choose $O_{\epsilon}$ such that the outer measure of $O_{\epsilon} \backslash A$ is less than $\epsilon$ and take the countable intersection $G$ of them. Then $G$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set covering $A$ and $G \backslash A$ is null.

Comment: If you want something from below, then this is true: For every measurable set $A$ there is a countable union of compact set $W = \bigcup K_n $ such that $A \backslash W$ is null.